# Grouping all shapesVBA excel /Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I created macro that allows me to open word from specific path then positioning differents shapes in different area in that `ActiveDocument`
What I want is when opening word is done and modifying shapes also is done 
all shapes in that active document Grouped together 
this my code for opening word

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Dim shp As Object
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True

Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(Sheets("Path").Range("B2").Value)
With wrdDoc
```

and this is code of grouping

```
wrdDoc.ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
Selection.ShapeRange.Group
```

I didnt succed to adapt it an error is keeping showing to me 
[image]

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: this contains excel elements `Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(Sheets("Path").Range("B2").Value)`

Comment: this line  `wrdDoc.ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll
`

Comment: are you sure that this line does not fail? `Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(Sheets("Path").Range("B2").Value)`

Comment: yes I'm 100% sure  what I want is to find solution how to groupe all shapes without exception in that active page only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to all who helped me for this
Solution for my question after a little bit of thinking

```
wrdDoc.Shapes.Range(Array("Groupe 19", "Group 646", "Image 652", "Group643", "Image 1", "Text Box 642", "Zone de texte 2")).Group
```

:D
Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

the excel stuff misdirected me, you should have mentioned that you were getting filenames from a worksheet

`wrdDoc` is a document object. `ActiveDocument` is also a document object

`wrdDoc.ActiveDocument` is like saying `ActiveDocument.ActiveDocument` ... this is bad

just use `wrdDoc.Shapes.SelectAll` or `ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll`

Comment: ah yes, I tested it but I'm still  can't grouping shapes now  the problem is here `Selection.ShapeRange.Group` @ jsotola  erreur message is  the same for the second line also

Comment: anyone can help me with  this  maybe you :D  @Siddharth Rout

Comment: i think that you cannot group shapes on multiple pages

Comment: and grouping  shapes in  that  active Page ?

Comment: i do not think that there is an ActivePage object

Comment: you say that you keep posting questions. you need to do more work yourself  ... i selected two shapes on a page and i was able to group them using the context menu (right mouse click) ..... then i selected two shapes on two pages and the option for grouping was greyed out  .... why have you not tried this yourself?  ... you would have known then, that you cannot group all shapes in a multi-page document. ... i did an internet search and found how to group all shapes on one page.  it took about 10 minutes to find.  .... i think that you can do the same

Comment: I did all  the  search   ...  and  I posted here  for  a  problem   I think not  for a some Unknowing syntax ...  I tried and followed many tuto  but I got this error that I couldn't solve so is that a problem for  you µ?????????????????????*

Comment: it is not a problem  .... do an internet search for `vba word select all shapes on one page` and you will find the answer